# Symfony 2, Gedmo Tree: dropdown select sorted by title

Tags: symfony, sorting, drop-down-menu, tree

I'm trying to create a dropdown select menu from my directories. Each directory has subdirectories and I'm using a Gedmo Tree Extension to implement it. I created dropdown in this way:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('parentDirectory', 'entity', array(
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Directories',
                'class' => 'TestTestBundle:Directory',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'hidden nextSelect 2-select'),
                'empty_value' => 'Choose directory',
                'property' => 'indentedName',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(DirectoryRepository $r) {
            return $r->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.root', 'ASC')
                    ->addOrderBy('c.lft', 'ASC');
        }
```

It works fine, but I need to order all directories also by its title. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
->orderBy('c.root, c.lvl, c.title', 'ASC')
```

'lft' doesn't take into account for 'lvl' and 'title'